# Riemann sum on divergent interval

Tags: real-analysis

Can anybody give me some hints on how to prove rigorously such a statement?
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=0,\Delta t=1/n}^{n}f(t) = \int_{0}^\infty f(t)\ dt
\end{equation}
The sum on $t$ has an increment $\Delta t = 1/n$. For Riemann sum, the interval is finite and fixed. But here, the interval is from $0$ to n, which diverges as $n$. So we cannot apply Riemann sum directly. Much appreciated if anyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean $n \to 0$ there?

Comment: Very sorry. Serious typo. I really mean $n\rightarrow \infty$. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: There is something called 'direct Riemann integrability'. I don't think existence of improper integral implies direct Riemann integrability. One place where this concept is discussed is page 146 of "Branching Processes", by Athreya and Ney

Comment: I do not understand your $\sigma$ notation.  You should specify more carefully what it means.  If the sum starts at $t=0$, has an increment of $1/n$, and ends at $t=n$, then the sum has about $n^2$ terms?  If so, why divide only by $n$?